# Is there geodesic surface which like the plane in $R^n$

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry

When I read the Riemannian geometry, special the geodesic curve, I feel there should be concept similar to geodesic curve, but it has high dimension. Similar to geodesic means that it has some minimum property. For example , for any $a,b,c\in M$ which are not in a geodesic curve, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with $\dim M\ge 3$,  the geodesic surface is $S(a,b,c)$ which satisfy
$$
\partial S(a,b,c) =\gamma(a,b)\cup\gamma(a,c)\cup\gamma (b,c)
$$
where $\partial S(a,b,c)$ is the boundary of $S(a,b,c)$, $\gamma(a,b)$ is the minimum  geodesic curve connect $a,b$. And
$$
S(a,b,c)=\bigcup\limits_{p,q\in \partial S(a,b,c)}\gamma(p,q)
$$

I feel when $a,b,c$ closing to each other, $S(a,b,c)$ is well defined.  It should have minimum area for ones have same boundary.  Seemly, it become the minimum surface...

I feel this concept should be useful, whether there is similar concept ?

Comment: If you do this on a sphere, which is the "right" surface:  the inside or the outside?

Comment: @Randall  I miss the dimension of $M$ should be $\ge 3$ if we consider $2-$dimensional geodesic surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of a [totally geodesic submanifold](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Totally_geodesic_submanifold). If $(M,g)$ is a manifold and $S\subset M$ is a submanifold then $S$ is totally geodesic if the geodesics of $S$ with the metric induced by $g$ are also geodesics in the larger manifold $M.$ For example, in $\mathbb R^n,$ the geodesic submanifolds are the affine linear subspaces. In a sphere $S^n,$ the geodesic submanifolds are the "equitorial" subspheres in $S^n$ (i.e. subspheres whose great circles are great circles of $S^n$). See the link for more information.